# get file name from JavaScript array by it's extension

Tags: javascript

How can I get the not allowed files name from `filesList` array after I filtered it by its extension.

```
<script>
    // 1- this is the files user has selected
    let filesList = ["000.webm", "001.ini", "01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg", "04.jpg"];
    // 2- get extensions from selected files
    let selectedFilesExt =  ["webm", "ini", "jpg", "jpg", "jpg", "jpg"];
    // 3- this is the allowed extensions
    let allowedExt =["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "dwg", "psd", "pdf", "docx", "txt", "zip", "rar", 
"exe", "max"];
    // 4- check if selected files extensions is in allowed extensions and display the not allowed extensions
    let notAllowedExt = ["webm", "ini"];
    // i need to get full name for the not allowed extensions files from filesList array
    // in this case i need to get array like this ["000.webm", "001.ini"]
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please share your attempt? This seems to be relatively straight forward task. **Hint:** Loop over `fileList` and check it current file is of type in `notAllowedExt`. If yes, create a new list and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const filesList = ["000.webm", "001.ini", "01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg", "04.jpg"];
const allowedExt =["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "dwg", "psd", "pdf", "docx", "txt", "zip", "rar", 
"exe", "max"];


const notAllowedExt = filesList.filter(file => !allowedExt.includes(/(?:\.([^.]+))?$/.exec(file)[1]))
```

We filter a list of selected by user files and pass as a condition another function which checks if selected by a user file is on an allowed list or not and we return opposite because we want to list only extensions which is not allowed.

A regular expression should work for the following file names and return an extension:

```
"file.name.with.dots.txt".  // 'txt'
"file.txt"                  // 'txt'
"file"                      // undefined
""                          // undefined
null                        // undefined
undefined                   // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need two arrays. fileList and allowedExt. Loop through your fileList array and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the filename. Check with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) if the extension in your allowedExt array exists. If it doesn't fit, the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) writes it to the notAllowed array.

```js
const filesList = ["000.webm", "001.ini", "01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg", "04.jpg"];
const allowedExt =["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "dwg", "psd", "pdf", "docx", "txt", "zip", "rar", 
"exe", "max"];

const notAllowed = filesList.filter(oFile => {
    if(allowedExt.indexOf(oFile.split(".")[1]) === -1){ //if the extension of file in allowed array return true
    return true;
  }
})  

console.log(notAllowed);
```

Comment: Please add explanation. It maybe obvious for you but for readers, it might not